# Job delay is not started again after canceling

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, jobs

So when I press a button I need to wait 3 seconds before executing another method, I worked that out with the followin

```
val job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch(Dispatchers.Default, CoroutineStart.DEFAULT) {
    delay(THREE_SECONDS)
    if (this.isActive)
        product?.let { listener?.removeProduct(it) }
}



override fun onRemoveProduct(product: Product) {
        job.start()
    }
```

now, if I press a cancel button right after I start the job I stop the job from happening and that is working fine

```
 override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v?.id) {
            R.id.dismissBtn -> {
                job.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when I execute again the `onRemoveProduct` that executes the `job.start()` it will not start again, seems like that `job.isActive` never yields to true, why is this happening ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Job` once cancelled cannot be started again. You need to do that in a different way. One way is to create a new job everytime `onRemoveProduct` is called.

```kotlin
private var job: Job? = null

fun onRemoveProduct(product: Product) {
    job = scope.launch {
        delay(THREE_SECONDS)
        listener?.removeProduct(product) // Assuming the two products are same. If they aren't you can modify this statement accordingly.
    }
}

fun cancelRemoval() { // You can call this function from the click listener
    job?.cancel()
}
```

Also, in this line of your code `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch(Dispatchers.Default, CoroutineStart.DEFAULT)`,

- You shouldn't/needn't create a new coroutine scope by yourself. You can/should use the already provided `viewModelScope` or `lifecycleScope`. They are better choices as they are lifecycle aware and get cancelled at the right time.
- `Dispatchers.Main` is useless because it gets replaced by `Dispatchers.Default` anyways. `Dispatchers.Default` is also not required here because you aren't doing any heavy calculations (or calling some blocking code) here.
- `CoroutineStart.DEFAULT` is the default parameter so you could have skipped that one.

And you also need not check `if (this.isActive)` because

> If the [Job] of the current coroutine is cancelled or completed while `delay` is waiting, it immediately resumes with [CancellationException].

Comment: Dispatchers.Default is also useless because blocking code is never called.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Edited the answer.

Comment: I cannot use viewmodelscope or lifecyclescope since this runs on a job class and not in any of those